# How do you exclude a page element from triggering a jQuery blur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onblur

I have an `<input>` that when focused on it shows a suggest drop down. When anything else is clicked the suggestions disappear. The problem is that I cannot seem to figure out to make it so that when the suggest `<div>` is clicked the blur event does not run.

Heres some of the HTML:

```
<label id="testTagsLabel">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" name="tags" id="testTags" placeholder="Ex: Poem, Edgar Allen Poe">
<div id="tagSuggest">
<ul>
<li class="tagSuggestTag">testtag</li>
<li class="tagSuggestTag">testtag2</li>
<li class="tagSuggestTag">testtag3</li>
<li class="tagSuggestTag">testtag4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Heres some of the JavaScript:

```
  $('#testTags').focus(
     function(){
        $('#tagSuggest').show();
     });

  $('#testTags').blur(
     function(){
        $('#tagSuggest').hide();
     });
```

Comment: @guidhouse just added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$("#yourinput").blur(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is(".suggestDiv")) {
        // close the suggest div
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** (oops, the code above doesn't work as I thought it would)

This should work:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("#suggest")) {
        $("#suggest").hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNVCL/

**UPDATE2:**

I forgot that you still need blur, because you probably want to hide the suggest div when you switch into another input by hitting tab. Here's an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNVCL/1/

Clicking anywhere still closes the suggest div (except on the suggest div itself or the input) as well as hitting tab to switch to another input. Still needs improvements, but you should be able to pick up from here.

Comment: Does not work because e.target is always the input on a blur event.

Comment: Oops, I had the right idea in my head but "worded it" wrong. Updated the answer along with a demo

Comment: You should bind/unbind the document event listener when the popup is shown/hidden, and include the input itself in the exclusion.

Comment: thanks, with a little editing (from @Pierre suggestion) I am up and running.

Comment: Updated answer again. Still needs improvements but should be more than enough to get the OP up and running

Comment: Amazing that you wrote the quite same code as my "dirty hack version" (anonymous function and hack variable) :)

Comment: Great minds think alike? `:P` Or more likely, that was the most viable solution, even if somewhat hacky :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the blur event because it's impossible to make the difference between a blur caused by a click on the suggest box and another blur (tab, window blur, right click, ...).

A workaround given by @dakis is to use the click event on the document but the suggest box to close the box. I suggest to dynamically add and remove the document click handler to avoid overhead, and to allow the user to click in the field without closing the box.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvwPn/

In addition I made the box to close when TAB is pressed. I also added a dirty hack version (commented) which uses the blur event and a big hack using a timeout (since the two events are fired independently, the delay depends on the client browser and speed... yep it's a dirty hack).

Comment: I did almost the same in my latest jsFiddle revision :) Voting this up for your effort and comments

Comment: One question though, why do you think it necessary to dynamically add/remove the document event listener? In my example, it is added only once, when the DOM is ready

Comment: Because each time the user will click on the document, even if the box is not shown, it will try to hide() it. Imagine each widget in the page do the same, it can become an issue on a big app. Worse if the same box is used in another context, a click would unexpectedly hide it.